# Does Microsoft's bot framework support Slack's Real Time Messaging API?

Tags: botframework, slack-api

We cannot open our slack app to be accessible to public, but our app can make calls to internet. I planned to use Slack RTM api to open web sockets to talk to Slack. Does bot framework support web socket?